# jQuery - add editable and draggable elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I use jQuery and I call a backend system with AJAX / JSON to get a list of projects which should be listed as small notes, like this one: http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/sticky-notes.jpg

```
function getAllProjects() {
    $.getJSON("allprocets, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(id, data) {
            alert(data.id);
            alert(data.name);
        });
    });
}
```

and I have a HTML div area in which the project notes should be placed:

```
<div id="projectlist">

</div>
```

But how can I create with jQuery such elements which are editable (the name which is printed on the note) and draggable (only in this projectlist area)?
Draggable will work, if I add for example a CSS class

```
class="draggable"
```

include jQuery UI and set

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
```

But first, I have to render the project list and make notes...
Does anyone know and can help me?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the sticky note the background image of a div element, then update the html of said div element with the text (and html) you need inserted.

```
<div id="projectlist">
    <div class="project" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-image: url('sticky-notes.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        // text
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery - Insert content like so...

```
function insert_content() {
    $('.project').html('<h1>Heading</h1><ul><li>Step 1</li><li>Step 2</li></ul><p>Project description</p>');
    }
```

Maybe I'm not getting it... Which step are you having a problem with?

Comment: Thank you. The background-image is not needed, because I will take a colored background with CSS3 features (shadows). But my main problem is, to render this with jQuery.

Comment: Does the above edit help? Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: I do this: $('#projectlist').append('<div class="draggable" style="height:100px;width:100px;">new paragraph</div>'); and then after the loop, because I will get more than one project, I make this: $(".draggable").draggable(); but the elements are not draggable within my div id="projectlist"

Comment: Are you assigning your draggable elements as draggable within the same function as your append statement?

Comment: Awesome, what was the problem?